# Applying SVG filter (feConvolveMatrix) using CSS to sharpen image

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to apply a SVG filter, `feConvolveMatrix`, to an image using CSS. This works great. However, when applying the filter in Safari (on a Retina display) the effect is anything but right.

Using the snippet below, hovering the image sharpens it. In Chrome and Firefox this has the desired effect. Both on my external monitor (low PPI) and on my MacBook Pro Retina display (high PPI). In Safari it does have desired effect on my external monitor but it does not when using the Retina display.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Safari? I've googled without luck so any help is appreciated.

**Note:** I'm using random [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/) images. Rerun the snippet to get a better image subject. Full page recommended.

```css
#img-subject:hover {
  filter: url(#sharpen);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SVG feConvolveMatrix filter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img id="img-subject" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" /> 
    <svg>
      <filter id="sharpen">
        <feConvolveMatrix order="3" preserveAlpha="true" kernelMatrix="-1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 -1"/>
      </filter>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I first thought of setting an an explicit [`kernelUnitLength`](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#element-attrdef-feconvolvematrix-kernelunitlength), but [this bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84610) says it isn't implemented, and now it's deprecated anyway...

Comment: I found this as well. Both `kernelUnitLength` and `filterRes` are deprecated.